# How to disable error_reporting() function after the first usage

Tags: php, joomla

I have a following problem: My friend has a Joomla portal with quite old components: EZ Autos, EZ Portal and EZ Feeds. They lack any support now and one of the pages (Profile edit page) displays as a blank page.

Is there any way to set PHP `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and then disable further changes to `error_reporting(0);`? Someone who created the components disabled error_reporting in a unknown location and the one page causes an error that I can't read.

Comment: no, but I guess you could issue your command to enable it after those components have been included in the script? Or do the components disable the error reporting when their functions are actually executed (rather than just when the scripts are included)? You should be able to see the source anyway I think to know how it's done? You could even just modify them to remove the line(s) which disable this? Since they're not supported anymore, presumably that won't conflict with any future updates, as there won't be any.

Comment: Hm. I looked at the problem in detail and at the end I downloaded all the files from the server and searched all of them using Sublime Text for `error_reporting(0);`.